# React Spring Change Animation Direction based on next component index

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-spring

I'm working from this example, which is from the React Spring docs: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/pmndrs/react-spring/tree/master/demo/src/sandboxes/simple-transition?file=/src/App.tsx

My use-case is different because I need be able to go back and forth between components, and **change the animation direction based on next component index**. If the next panel index is greater than the current one, I want the current panel to exit left and the new panel to enter right. If the new index is less than, I want the reverse.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import {
  useTransition,
  animated,
  AnimatedProps,
  useSpringRef,
  config,
} from '@react-spring/web'


import { schemas } from 'types'

import BottomPanelContent from './BottomPanelContent'

interface Props {
  // the BottomPanelContent expects the contents of one of these as a prop
  panels: schemas['ModuleObjects']['TextWithRotatingBottomPanel']['config']['bottom_panels']
  // I have a parent component handling changing the state between the indexes
  currentPanelIdx: number
}

export default function Animator({ panels, currentPanelIdx }: Props) {
  const [prevPanelIdx, setPrevPanelIdx] = React.useState(-1)
  const [from, setFrom] = React.useState<string>('translateX(100%)')
  const [leave, setLeave] = React.useState<string>('translateX(-100%)')

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const isGoingForward = currentPanelIdx > prevPanelIdx
    setFrom(`translateX(${isGoingForward ? '100' : '-100'}%)`)
    setLeave(`translateX(${isGoingForward ? '-100' : '100'}%)`)
    setPrevPanelIdx(currentPanelIdx)
  }, [currentPanelIdx])

  const transRef = useSpringRef()
  const transitions = useTransition(currentPanelIdx, {
    ref: transRef,
    keys: null,
    initial: { transform: 'translateX(0%)' },
    from: { transform: from },
    enter: { transform: 'translateX(0%)' },
    leave: { transform: leave },
    exitBeforeEnter: true,
    delay: 0,
    config: config.default,
    trail: 0,
  })

  React.useEffect(() => {
    transRef.start()
  }, [prevPanelIdx])

  const panelElements: ((
    props: AnimatedProps<{ style: CSSProperties }>
  ) => React.ReactElement)[] = panels.map(p => ({ style }) => (
    <animated.div style={{ ...style, minWidth: '100%' }}>
      <BottomPanelContent {...p} />
    </animated.div>
  ))

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        willChange: 'transform',
      }}>
      {transitions((style, i) => {
        const Panel = panelElements[i]
        return <Panel style={style} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is not working properly. The panels always leave in whatever direction would have been correct for the transition when they entered. Ie if you go from `0 - 1 - 2` works, but `0 - 1 - 0` results in `1` exiting to the left, when it should have exited to the right. Here's a gif to show what is happening:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4fbc.jpg

I had hoped that waiting to call `transRef.start()` until `prevPanelIdx` changed would be enough to update the styles getting passed from `transitions`. However I might be approaching this incorrectly. Potentially I should be using the dependency array in the `useTransition` hook, or passing functions to `from` and `leave` instead of what Ii'm doing now, but the documentation both of these options seems spotty to me. I made some efforts in those directions but failed as well.

I'm considering making a PR to the react spring docs if I get this working, as it seems to me a trivial case that could really help their docs out.

I can look into adding a demo if that's helpful, it will be a bit of work so let me know in the comments if that's needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach I took was not very good. I seem to have a better approach by tinkering with the sandbox from the documentation: you can see my updated sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-archimedes-p5k8ox?file=/src/App.tsx

I still need to do more work to apply this to the code in my example, and will update this answer when I do that.